# jQuery toggle underline

Tags: jquery, css, toggle, slide, underline

I've got a menu that toggles by clicking a link. I'd like that link to underline when the menu is visibile, and have no decoration when it's hidden. I can't get the function correct: the underline displays when you first press the trigger button, but stays after the menu is hidden.

Thanks for your help!

HTML

```
<div id="trigger">
        <div id="menu">MENU<br/></div>
        <div id="navdrop">
            <a class="a transition" id="item1" href="Pages/music.html" alt="MUSIC">MUSIC</a><br />
            <a class="a transition" id="item2" href="Pages/photos.html" alt="PHOTOS">PHOTOS</a><br />
            <a class="a transition" id="item3" href="Pages/biography.html" alt="BIOGRAPHY">BIOGRAPHY</a><br />
            <a class="a transition" id="item4" href="Pages/discography.html" alt="DISCOGRAPHY">DISCOGRAPHY</a><br />
            <a class="a transition" id="item5" href="Pages/contact.html" alt="CONTACT">CONTACT</a><br />
            <a class="a" id="item6" href="http://www.blog.fernandogaribay.com" alt="BLOG" target="_blank">BLOG</a><br />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Javascript

```
    $('#trigger').click(function (){
        $('#navdrop').slideToggle(400);
        $('#menu').css("text-decoration", "underline");
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#trigger').click(function (){
    $('#navdrop').slideToggle(400, function(){
         $('#menu').toggleClass('underline');
    });
});
```

## css

```
#menu.underline {
   text-decoration: underline;
}
```

## [demo on the go](http://jsfiddle.net/reigel/28n7q/)

Comment: this will still toggle the class before the slide has finished

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the callback portion of the .slideToggle()

```
$('#trigger').click(function (){
    $('#navdrop').slideToggle(400, function() {
        $('#menu').toggleClass('underline');
    });

});
```

This will trigger the css change after the slide has completed.

I also suggest you set up a `.underline` class in your css to set the underline.  As others have I will also give you the css rule for this, very basic.  Using a generic `.underline` also improves reusability as you can use it anywhere in your site to set the underline text-decoration

```
.underline {
   text-decoration: underline;
}
```